# Inverse direction of jQuery UI resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a floating sidebar which is located on the right of the page which I want to be able to resize using a handle on the left of the container.

At the moment, when I drag the sidebar using the handle, it makes the sidebar wider when dragging right, and smaller when dragging left - I wan't it to do the inverse of this. i.e., dragging to the left increases the size of the sidebar etc..

I would prefer to not change the html structure and hopefully have a simple line of javascript to fix the problem - please help!

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c01gat3/us8vktjq/

html

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="drag">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background-color: blue;
}
#drag{
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:black;
  cursor:ew-resize;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#sidebar').resizable({
  minWidth: 100,
  handles: { "w" : $("#drag") }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the associated CSS file.

Add the following reference to your HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Adjust your HTML code to include the needed classes:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="drag" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w">
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/us8vktjq/2/

Read more here: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

Comment: Thanks.. I did have the associated CSS in my project (forgot to add to fiddle), was just missing the required classes on the handle.